# Why does the AMD Proprietary graphics driver not support old cards?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I've got a rather old notebook with an AMD ATI 3200 graphics card inside. Now I use XUbuntu 13.04 on it and found out that there is no support for this chipset anymore, due to some X.org conflicts.
But before that I used Manjaro (user-friendly arch derivate), where my graphics card got automatically dedected and the proprietary driver was used, I even got the catalyst control center.
Right now I am trying to create the package myself with the download from the AMD website but I don't think that will work. Has anybody got an idea why I can't use the driver on Ubuntu, what I can do to use it and if it's a bad idea to create the package myself with the newest package from the website?

EDIT: Ok, got a solution now: Simply use this [repo](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx), which downgrades your x-server to 1.12.4, which enables you to install the proprietary drivers.
According to the launchpad site, do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Comment: As far as I know AMD has declared the chipset end of life and no longer develops drivers for it. As newer Xorg versions emerge, compatibility deteriorates. Using 12.04 LTS might help.

Comment: Did you tried the radeon driver?

Answer (score 1):

Hardware companies do not support their products with software updates forever. In this case, AMD announced that support for cards before [Radeon HD 5000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_5000_Series) would be ended. To put this in context, HD 5000 (still supported) was released in 2009, HD 4000 (unsupported) was released in 2008.

Downgrading your x-server is not recommended, it may cause dependency or stability problems with your system. Also note that the [makson96 repository](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) does not support recent releases of Ubuntu:

> If there will be no more driver updates made by AMD, than this
>   repository will not support Ubuntu 13.10 and beyond
>   ...
>   Ubuntu 12.04.3 is not supported.

For more details see [Launchpad #1058040 fglrx-installer not working with AMD Radeon/Mobility Radeon HD 2000-4000 cards in Quantal](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1058040).